# Как вытащить текст из script в HTML парсингом

Tags: python, beautiful-soup

Принялся изучать питон, всё шло гладко до того момента, пока на тестовом сайте, который я решил распарсить, не встретился тег script, мне нужно вытащить цену, на скриншоте обвёл её, вот код, который у меня есть. Также пытался обратиться к div, но это выдаёт ошибку.

```
def get_content(html):
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
items = soup.find_all('div', class_='b-post')
jobs = []
for item in items:

    jobs.append({
        'title': item.find('a', class_='b-post__link').get_text(strip=True),
        'link': HOST + item.find('a', class_='b-post__link').get('href'),
        'price': item.find('script', type_='text').get_text(),

    })
print(jobs)
print(len(jobs))
```

Ошибка в последнем объекте словаря.

```
  File "C:/Users/Nikzem/PycharmProjects/parser_forumok/parser.py", line 23, in get_content
 'price': item.find('script', type_='text').get_text(),
  AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Он вряд ли найдёт скрипт (это JS, а BS работает с HTML). Тебе нужно привязаться к другому тегу. Как именно ты пытался привязаться к тегу div? Я бы попробовал так: `items.find('div', {'class': 'Всё, что находится в кавычках класса, который ты выделил зелёным'}).text`, если это не поможет или даст избыточную информацию попробуй сделать то же самое, но с тегом  то есть `items.find('a', {'class': 'Всё что входит в класс a'}).text`. Важно! Для поиска с помощью bs4 ты должен убедиться, что класс, который ты ищешь уникален. Как это сделать? Нажимаешь правой кнопкой мыши на строку далее посмотреть код или исследовать элемент (зависит от браузера) далее смотришь на класс и копируешь его. после этого нажимаешь ctrl+f (когда курсор стоит в HTML коде) и вставляешь туда скопированный ранее класс. Если он уникален- всё хорошо, если таких классов несколько, но ты точно знаешь, что нужный тебе класс всегда стоит, например, вторым, можно сделать так `items.find_all('div', {'class': 'то, что стоит после искомого класса'})[2].text` Этот код найдёт третий класс (нумерация в python начинается с нуля- помни это), если же ты не знаешь на каком месте твой класс и их несколько можно попробовать найти необходимый тебе класс по тексту. Например, найдём все классы
`items.find_all('div', {'class': 'то, что стоит после искомого класса'})`
теперь циклом пройдём по каждому из них и узнаем какой из них содержит необходимы нам текст

```
for item in items:
   if 'искомый текст' in item.text:
   print('тег найден')
```

Один из вариантов должен помочь. Удачи в изучении!